# Div dentro de otro div. [DOM]

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente **HTML**:

```
<div class="tabla">
     <div class="impostores">
          //Contenido del forEach
     </div>
</div>
```

Tengo el siguiente código **JS**:

**Primeramente un array de objetos:**

```
let jugadores = [
    {"nombre": "Vladi","id": "rojo"},
    {"nombre": "Melen","id": "azul"},
    {"nombre": "Gabri","id": "verde"},
    {"nombre": "Lucia","id": "amarillo"},
    {"nombre": "Brian","id": "morado"},
    {"nombre": "Jesús","id": "turquesa"},
    {"nombre": "David","id": "rosa"},
    {"nombre": "Dario","id": "negro"},
    {"nombre": "Mario","id": "blanco"}
];
```

**Seguidamente el forEach que recorre los elementos del array de objetos:**

```
jugadores.forEach(function(jugador) {
    console.log("Nombre: " + jugador.nombre +" |"+ " Edad: " + jugador.id);
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    
    div.textContent = jugador.nombre;
    div.className = "impostor";
    div.id = jugador.id;
    console.log(div);
    divConDatos = div;
});
```

Además se duplica el último elemento:
[image]

**¿Cómo podría insertar el `divConDatos` en el div con la clase `impostores` ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ya has hecho casi todo

Ya has hecho casi todo el trabajo. Solo tienes que modificar algunas cosas.

Por ejemplo, agregar en tu código **JavaScript** la siguiente línea:

```js
const impostores = document.querySelector(".impostores");
```

Para tener referencia al elemento **HTML** que contiene la clase **impostores** y luego, ubicarlo en:

```js
jugadores.forEach(function() {
    ...
    impostores.append( div );
});
```

Veamos esto funcionando en la siguiente **Demo** utilizando el mismo código que has utilizado, pero con un mínimo cambio que he comentado:

```js
// Hacemos referencia al elemento que contiene la clase 
// «impostores»:
const impostores = document.querySelector(".impostores");

let jugadores = [
  { nombre: "Vladi", id: "rojo" },
  { nombre: "Melen", id: "azul" },
  { nombre: "Gabri", id: "verde" },
  { nombre: "Lucia", id: "amarillo" },
  { nombre: "Brian", id: "morado" },
  { nombre: "Jesús", id: "turquesa" },
  { nombre: "David", id: "rosa" },
  { nombre: "Dario", id: "negro" },
  { nombre: "Mario", id: "blanco" }
];

jugadores.forEach(function(jugador) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");

  div.textContent = jugador.nombre;
  div.className = "impostor";
  div.id = jugador.id
  
  // Agregando cada impostor al elemento que contiene 
  // la clase impostores:
  impostores.append(div);
});
```

```html
<div class="tabla">
  <div class="impostores"></div>
</div>
```

> Si desde el navegador Web inspeccionas los elementos que contienen la clase `impostor` podrás observar que efectivamente se han insertado dentro del elemento con la clase `impostores`.